# changing the value of a currency based on a selected country in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am building a rails ecommerce application and would like to integrate a currency exchange system were visitors can click on a check box and a list of countries will be displayed and when clicked on the value of the currencies of products on the site changes to the value of the selected countries currency. Is there a rails gem that connects to a currency exchange server and authomaticall converts the currency for me or any ideas of how i can accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out the [money gem](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money)
There seems to be some workaround to do exactly what you want to do, however it'll give you a decent base to what you're aiming for.

Comment: @UchennaOkafor how you fixed this issue, could you write it as answer?

Comment: @SachinSingh added an example as my answer

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is have the currency code like USD NGN EUR,so which ever currency the user selects has its currency code saved in a session or cookie having in mind that your default currency is set to which ever one you want to use.

Then Install the [google currency](https://github.com/RubyMoney/google_currency) gem which gives you access to real time exchange rate.

Assuming all these is set what we will do is

```
require 'money'
require 'money/bank/google_currency'
bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new
rate = bank.get_rate(:NGN, :USD).to_f
```

For this example, i am simply getting the rate of 1 naira to $1

now that i no the rate all i have to do is find a way to convert the item price to selected currency.

Assuming the user selects $ then the `session[:selected_currency] = "USD"`

in our product model we have the following

```
##Assuming default currency is NGN so it defaults to NGN if no currency code
require 'money'
require 'money/bank/google_currency'
    def converted_price(currency = :NGN)
          bank = Money::Bank::GoogleCurrency.new
          rate = bank.get_rate(:NGN, currency).to_f
          price = item_amount / rate
          price
    end
```

so in our view we can have `<%= @product.converted_price(session[:selected_currency])%>`

I haven't tested this but this would give you an idea of how i solved the issue.